# Concatenating url in jsp

Tags: java, html, jsp, concatenation

I want to concatenate url with the value of string variable.
Example

```
string filename="example"
string extention="txt"
<a href="myuploads/(value of filename).(value of extention)">
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: String finalUrl = fileName + extension; ???!!

Comment: my files are in myuploads folder. so url looks like href="myuploads/example.txt"

Comment: maybe you should read some basic literature before starting...

Comment: ya thanx for your advice.. i tried but i dont know its not working.so can you please give me answer.

Comment: @DipalDarji Please accept the answer if you satisfy.

Answer (score 3):

```
String filename = "example"
String extension = "txt"
String url = "myuploads/" + filename + "." + extension
```

I the JSP :

```
<a href='<%= url%>'></a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of declaring another variable it can be done like this as well :

```
<a href="myuploads/<%=filename %>.<%=extension %>"></a>
```

Usage of unnecessary variables must be curbed whenever and wherever applicable .